# elgg 1.8.0.1 installation on linux giving segmentation fault

Tags: apache-2.2, php, segmentation-fault

**i tried `elgg 1.8.0.1` on windows XP and it installed successfully but when i tried on fedora 12 it is not able to install**. here is what happens i extracted the zip file for elgg 1.8.0.1 in `/var/www/html` now when i use `firefox` to go to the url `http://localhost/elgg-1.8.0.1` it asks me whether i want to open or save `install.php` ,but when i open it with a text editor or if i save it and then open it *its an empty file*. *The size of file is 0 bytes*.
And when i use Konqueror to do the above it displays a timeout error instantly(at the moment i press enter).

i checked the error log of apache and it displays the following line

```
child pid 2147 exit signal Segmentation Fault(11)
```

**I was able to install elgg 1.7.11 on fedora successfully,also i am able to run other php files nicely.I wonder what can go wrong *because elgg 1.8.0.1 installs successfully in windows XP.** *(Note:I have the appropriate permissions for reading writing and executing scripts in the elgg 1.8.0.1 directory)*

---

**UPDATE:** 
i tried `strace php install.php` and i got a long trace of which i am only showing the last few lines

```
mmap2(NULL, 11905, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0xb77cb000
munmap(0xb77cb000, 11905)               = 0
close(3)                                = 0
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
time(NULL)                              = 1317422887

access("/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Calcutta", R_OK) = 0

access("/var/www/html/elgg-1.8.0.1/engine/settings.php", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Now any idea why there is this segmentation fault? I have read that infinite recursive function calls can cause seg faults but if that was the problem it wouldnt have run on windows. If i try to include a lot of files with `include` or `require` or `require_once` can it lead to php causing a segmentation fault?

Comment: This sounds like there may be an issue with `mod_php`.  Can you try creating a test PHP file with the contents, `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`?  When you access it from your browser, what happens?

Comment: @Redmumba yes i can create other php files and they are working correctly.As my question says i was able to successfully install elgg 1.7.11.

Comment: My bad, I am blind! :)  Just out of curiosity, have you tried doing something like executing it from the command line (i.e., `php install.php`)?  Also, have you enabled PHP logging in your `php.ini`?

Comment: @Redmumba yes i have enabled logging and updated my question to show the errors.Thanks

Comment: The superglobal notices have nothing to do with the segfault; the $_SERVER array is unavailable when running the CLI. Which database engine are you using?

Comment: @fuscata i am using mysql 5.1.4

Comment: any chance you have mhash PHP module installed? Any clues in the event log viewer?

Comment: @fuscata i cant find the `mhash` php module in both my linux `php.ini` file as well as windows `php.ini` file. Where can i find the event log viewer?

Comment: Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer or Run > eventvwr

Comment: @fuscata elgg is installed successfully on windows. i am facing this problem on linux(fedora 12)

Comment: Ah ok my mistake. Could you try: create another file in the same directory as index.php, called say `test.php` with only 1 line: `<?php echo 'test';` and browse to that file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1392/discussion-between-fuscata-and-lovesh)

Comment: I saw the _"core dumped"_. You should debug it with gdb and send `bt full` infos to elgg's developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in my php version. Updating to a later version solved the issue.